# Java Tiled2d game unit conversion

Tags: java, eclipse

Hey guys I'm messing around with Tiled2d and making a RPG game but I'm having difficulties with the conversion units since I'm using Box2d as well and have specified the Box2d constant as PPM = 100 (pixels per meter so effectively divided everything in the box2d world with this PPM).

I'm trying now to import objects for the collision meshes for the Tiled2d map(tmx) and the way I have done it is given below. I copied the code from another thread on this site but since I have the Box2d constant I'm having trouble making it work.

```
private static PolygonShape getRectangle(RectangleMapObject rectangleObject) {
    Rectangle rectangle = rectangleObject.getRectangle();
    PolygonShape polygon = new PolygonShape();
    Vector2 size = new Vector2((rectangle.x + rectangle.width * 0.5f) / ppt,
                               (rectangle.y + rectangle.height * 0.5f ) / ppt);
    polygon.setAsBox(rectangle.width * 0.5f / ppt,
                     rectangle.height * 0.5f / ppt,
                     size,
                     0.0f); 
    return polygon;
}
```

The above is the code I copied. The ppt is the pixel per tile used in Tiled2d which in my case is 8. I believe I have to put in my PPM constant somewhere in this code but I can't seem to understand where. This is the customised code I've tried.

```
  private static PolygonShape getRectangle(RectangleMapObject rectangleObject) {
    Rectangle rectangle = rectangleObject.getRectangle();
    PolygonShape polygon = new PolygonShape();
    Vector2 size = new Vector2((    (rectangle.x + (rectangle.width * 0.5f))/(PPM*0.25F)     ) / ppt,
                               (    (rectangle.y + (rectangle.height * 0.5f))/(PPM*0.125F)    ) / ppt);
    polygon.setAsBox( ((rectangle.width * 0.5f)/(PPM*0.5F)) / ppt,
                     ((rectangle.height * 0.5f)/(PPM*0.5F)) / ppt,
                     size,
                     0.0f); 
    return polygon;
}
```

But the collision meshes aren't exactly in the place I placed them in the map editor. Below is the collision meshes I placed in the map editor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNK2I.png

And below is the image of the object places I'm getting in the java game(eclipse). Its a bit faint but you can see the second box is above the first box which is not the case in the map editor. Maybe I have to put a minus sign somewhere?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U9BX.png